# Как получить столкновение объектов в игре?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx

Есть класс в библиотеке LIBGDX для проверки столкновений

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;   
Intersector.intersectRectangles(rectangle1, rectangle2, intersection);
```

Как реализовать его не понимаю. У меня имеются два класса `Bullet` и `Enemy` у них имеются свои координаты `Rectangles`.

К примеру, пуля летит по горизонтали и нужно сделать проверку на столкновение. В гугле искал код реализации, вроде находил что то похожее, но как то не получается реализовать это в коде.

Кто сталкивался с подобным классом столкновений? Подскажите, куда смотреть.

Пытаюсь написать условие с циклом `for` но выдает ошибку в r2:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index can't be >= size: 1 >= 1

Вот код, который я пытаюсь выполнить:

```
if(arrayBullet.size != 0){               
    Rectangle intersection = new Rectangle();
    for(int k=0;k<arrayBullet.size;k++){
        Rectangle r1 = arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect();                            
        Rectangle r2 = arrayBullet.get(num).getRect();
        if((Intersector.intersectRectangles(r1, r2, intersection))){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`num` — переменная объявлена в поле класса для быстрого доступа в циклах `for` который находится в методе `render`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все разобрался... невнимательность дает о себе знать... Всего лишь поменял буковку в r2 на букву k :)))

```
    if(arrayBullet.size != 0){               
        Rectangle intersection = new Rectangle();
        for(int k=0;k<arrayBullet.size;k++){
            Rectangle r1 = arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect();                            
            Rectangle r2 = arrayBullet.get(k).getRect();
        if((Intersector.intersectRectangles(r1, r2, intersection))){                    
            arrayBullet.removeIndex(k);
            arrayEnemy.removeIndex(num);
            break;
        }
        }
    }
```